# Defining two versions of << overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence, compound-assignment

Can someone tell me what is wrong when I try to overload `<<` in a slightly different way by using another symbol like `<<=`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Date { 
    int day, month, year, hour, minute, second;
    Date (int d, int m, int y, int h, int min, int s) { day = d;  month = m;  year = y;  hour = h;  minute = min;  second = s; }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Date&);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<= (std::ostream&, const Date&);  // Carries out << but without the hour, minute, and second.
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Date& d) {
    os << d.day << ' ' << d.month << ' ' << d.year << ' ' << d.hour << ' ' << d.minute << ' ' << d.second;
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator <<= (std::ostream& os, const Date& d) {
    os << d.day << ' ' << d.month << ' ' << d.year;
    return os;
}

int main () {     
    Date date(25, 12, 2021, 8, 30, 45);
    std::cout << "Today is " << date << '\n';  // Works fine
    std::cout << "Today is " <<= date << '\n';  // Does not work
}
```

If I use

```
std::cout << "Today is " <<= date;
```

It works fine, so what is the problem with adding in `<< '\n'` when std::ostream& is returned by `<<=`  ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah bitshift assignment, forgot that existed.

Comment: I'd recommend using member functions to get a formatted date string instead. As `>>=` is for bitwise stuff this would be a violation of POLA.

Comment: Why are you trying to bit shift a date?  The `operator<<=` is bit shift left and assign.  Doesn't make sense to bit shift a date.

Comment: Or, are you attempting to do stream insertion with assignment?

Comment: I'd recommend giving the `Date` type an accessor, let's say `day()`, providing  class which gets formatted differently but still using `operator<<`. As was pointed out, using `operator<<=` has two problems: it needs to be a member function and it has the wrong precedence. Further using an uncommon operator may look nifty but it is likely a usability issue.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the operator precedence this statement

```
std::cout << "Today is " <<= date << '\n';
```

is equivalent to

```
( std::cout << "Today is " ) <<= ( date << '\n' );
```

and the right most expression

```
( date << '\n' )
```

produces an error because such an operator is not defined for objects of the type `struct Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vlad from Moscow's answer,

```
(std::cout << "Today is " <<= date) << '\n';
```

is the simple fix.  Not as pretty as was desired, but works correctly.
Perhaps defining a derived class `DateAndTime` of `Date` that has the hours, minutes, and seconds and then overloading << for `DateAndTime` may be a more elegant, but longer, solution.